# Is there a way to check if my Taylor Expansion is correct?

Tags: analytic-geometry, taylor-expansion

I have an exam later and I need to do Taylor expansions of functions. I have questions like:

> Consider the map $F:\mathbb{R}^2_x \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2_y$, given by the equations
>
> $$y_1 = x_2 + x_1^2,$$
> $$y_2 = x_1 - x_2^3.$$
>
> Find the Taylor series of the local inverse map up to the terms of degree $4$.

and

> Let $f(x,y,z) = x + y + z + x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. Consider the surface
>
> $$S = \{f(x,y,z) = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$$
>
> near the origin. Compute the Taylor series of the function
>
> $$g = (x + y + 3yz)|_S$$
>
> at the origin in the coordinates $(y,z)$ up to degree $2$.

Now, I know how to do these questions, the only mistakes I make are algebraic ones, so I expand something wrong or mess up on my signs or whatever and I was just wandering if there was a way to check if my expansions are correct?